# Troubleshooting with php7 and memcached

Tags: memcached

I want to install memcached with php7, so I downloaded the actual php7.0-memcached package from the dotdeb repository.

But it doesn't work: I get following error in the nginx error files when I want to use memcached with my CMS: `recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream`==> 502

Answer (score -1):

First please check that memcached gives the permission to your domain to access to it. By default is only allowing 127.0.0.1 interface.
So you have 2 options, add your interface or makes your domain pointing to localhost in your /etc/hosts file.

To know if this is the cause of the problem, you can run this :

```
echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211
```

if you see

```
yourdomain.com [212.83.185.188] 11211 (?) : Connection refused
```

so that's probably the cause.